# Implementing Caching for REST resource

Tags: spring, rest, caching

I want to implement caching funtionality for Rest service that implemented in SpringBoot.

I found different way to implement this:

1. Use springs’s cache-abstraction(@cachable etc) that uses a internal in-memory caching using HashMap.
2. Use springs’s cache-abstraction(@cachable etc) with caching implementation like ehcache, caffeine etc.
3. HttpCaching where we need to set Cache-Control header and its different attribute.

   4. HttpCaching using ETAG.

Difficult to decide which one is the best solution and why?
Are all these ways are related to each other or not?

Please help out me with this.